# How to create a road with a certain trajectory using Python

Tags: python, animation, path

I wanted to ask if there is an automated way to create a road trajectory in Blender using Python.
In particular, I have the (x,y,z) of a road in Matlab:
[image: Circuit]

I would like to know how can I automatically create a road with these coordinates (as a centerline) using the Python API? If there is a tutorial or somebody that has done something similar, I would appreciate any help.

**EDIT AFTER GORGIOUS COMMENT:**

The code I have written is the following. It reads an excel file of all x,y,z and it saves it in a list of lists named `coords_list`. From that I can generate successfully the path that you can see the above picture. What I want is to extrude a road profile via Python code, so I can have a road.

```
import bpy
from bpy import ops
from mathutils import Vector
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

fileName = 'C:/some path.../_trajectory.xls'
# READ SIMULATION DATA
coords_list = []
excelF = pd.ExcelFile (fileName)
df = excelF.parse(0,header=None)   
coords_arr = df.to_numpy()
coords_list = coords_arr.tolist()

# make a new curve
crv = bpy.data.curves.new('crv', 'CURVE')
crv.dimensions = '3D'

# make a new spline in that curve
spline = crv.splines.new(type='NURBS')

# a spline point for each point
spline.points.add(len(coords_list)) # theres already one point by default

# assign the point coordinates to the spline points
for p, new_co in zip(spline.points, coords_list):
    p.co = (new_co + [1.0]) # (add nurbs weight)

# make a new object with the curve
obj = bpy.data.objects.new('object_name', crv)
bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(obj)


spline = bpy.data.objects["object_name"].data.splines[0]
spline.points.add(1)
spline.points[-1].co = (1,1,5,1)


points_coords = [p.co for p in spline.points]
```

Comment: Don't mind the -1. What's the format of your data ? csv ? txt ? xls ?

Comment: I export them from Matlab into an excel file and then in Python I read them as three 1D arrays.

Comment: Could you post your python code ?

Comment: @Gorgious I added it

Comment: Where does this fail ?

Comment: It doesn't fail; it works fine. My problem is that I do not know how to extrude a profile along a path using only Python. I am able to do it within the Blender UI, but I do not know how to do it with Python.

Comment: have you tried `bpy.data.objects["object_name"].data.extrude = 5` for instance ? Might need to set each point's tilt to 90° : `spline.points[i].tilt = 1.6708`